# To present or to give a presentation

Tags: vocabulary, present-tense

As part of a recruitment process, Bob was asked to 'present a finished product'. Bob took that literal and gave them a finished/packaged product as he thought this was the requirement. Instead, they wanted him to give a presentation of the final product. After apologising for his mistake, he checked the dictionary definition of *present* and after that, he still thinks his interpretation is valid and so he advised them to change their wording in the instructions to 'give a presentation of the finished product' to avoid confusion for future applicants (and generally for the sake of being more precise). They said that out of thousands of applicants Bob is the only one who misread that and they do not agree with him.

Common consent is not a compelling argument. Are there grammatical/linguistic reasons as to why their wording would be preferred to Bob's suggestion?

Comment: If somebody asks you to do something and you misunderstand what they asked for, it doesn't help to blame them for how they said it. Apologize for your misunderstanding and get on with it.

Comment: As @JohnLawler says, the time to insist you are right (which you are) is never, but certainly not before you are hired. If you are right and they are wrong, pushing your opnion does not define you as a team player. But you would never be happy there if they can't see their instructions were amgibuous.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the interpersonal aspect is the overriding issue, not English. No disrepect.

Comment: This is not about blame. I apologised and moved on with it. I just explained to them how I understood it and suggested them to make it clearer what they mean. I was surprised that they didn't agree with my suggestion and just asked if there is a better explanation than common consent. Thanks for your help

Comment: The only reason I gave the background information was for context as this is usually important when it comes to language and how it is interpreted and what the common assumptions are. Just trying to improve my English for professional usage as it is not my first language

Comment: The question is about an arguable ambiguity in the meaning of the word *present*, and it goes beyond what is obvious in the standard dictionary entries for that word. It is thus well within the scope of this site. The question is independent of whether it is, as a matter of Bob's career-advancing strategy, wise for him to insist on educating his potential employers about the ambiguity - whatever one thinks about that is not a good reason for preventing the question about the meaning from being answered here.

Comment: I’m not sure I even understand the question.  Are you saying that “Bob” heard the instruction “present a product”, and so he went out and got (bought?) something, wrapped it in gift wrap, tied a ribbon around it, and said “Here’s your present,” without having anything to say about the product?  No, everybody would interpret “present _____” to mean “make a presentation”. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: P.S. You might get a better response at our sister site, [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Scott, it seems that Bob created a prototype of the finished product and then **presented** (gave, delivered, submitted) that prototype to the committee for their evaluation (but without giving a speech about it). Note that *presented* sounds perfectly natural here, so an explanation is needed of why it is supposed to be obvious that this is not what was intended by the committee's request to 'present a finished product'.

Comment: FWIW, I don’t see any indication in the question that Bob created anything. “As part of a recruitment process” sounds like this was a job interview, possibly multi-day, possibly with morning and afternoon sessions. So I guess that Bob was not yet an employee of the company (Yosef seems to agree with this), and so not expected to do any substantial work, and that the interval between the two conversations was unlikely to be enough to create a product. It would be nice if the OP would come back and clarify.